# jQuery to only add a row if % entered is less than 100%

Tags: jquery

I have tried and had errors but the fields should appear only if the percentage entered is not 100%. For example if i enter 22% in the first percentage input field and 78% in the second percentage input field, an alert should say percentage has reached 100% But if 100% is not reached, it should continue adding input fields until they all add up to 100%

```
                $(document).ready(function () {

                $(document).on("focusout", ".ration, .percentage", function () {

                    var count = $('.newtextbox').length;

                    if (count < 5) {

                        $(content).append("<p><input type='text' class='newtextbox' id='ingredient" + count + "' placeholder='ingredient name'/> <input type='text' class='costPerTon' placeholder='cost per ton'/> <input type='text' class='percentage' placeholder='percent applied'/> <input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton" + count + "'/></p>");

                    } else {

                    alert('You have maximum elements allowed.')

                    }

                    $("input[type = 'button']").click(function () {

                    $(this).parent().remove();

                    });
                });
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z2FdP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the answer to your specific example/Fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("focusout", ".ration, .percentage", function () {

        var count = $('.newtextbox').length;

        var percent = 0;
        $(".percentage").each(function (i) {
            var pc = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/%/g, ""));

            if (!isNaN(pc)) {
                 percent += pc;
            }        
        });

        if (percent == 100)
        {
            alert('Reached 100%');
        }
        else if (percent > 100)
        {
            alert('Oops, you are over 100%');
        }
        else if (count < 5) {

            $('#content').append("<p><input type='text' class='newtextbox' id='ingredient" + count + "' placeholder='ingredient name'/> <input type='text' class='costPerTon' placeholder='cost per ton'/> <input type='text' class='percentage' placeholder='percent applied'/> <input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton" + count + "'/></p>");

        } else {

            alert('You have maximum elements allowed.')

        }

        $("input[type = 'button']").click(function () {

            $(this).parent().remove();

        });
    });
});
```

New fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/F76Tk/

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't work because query $(content) is wrong. I guess here has to be $("#content").

Comment: This will work in some browsers, but not others. For instance, it works in the latest Chrome. For consistency across browsers, the OP should rely on the identifier as you mentioned, rather than a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your problem is how to count the total % number entered in all inputs.

Here's how you do this:

```
var totalPercents = 0;

$("input").each(function (i, input) {
    var percent = $(input).val().replace(/%/g, "");

    if (!isNaN(percent)) {
         totalPercents += parseInt(percent);
    }

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vGZZ9/1/)

I'm sure you will figure out how to apply it to your code :)

Comment: Ok i see, thanks and sorry it is how to count total % only in the 3rd input which is the percentage field. The other two will be text

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var current_percent_sum = $('.value').get().map(function (value) {
        return $(value).data('value')
    }).reduce(function (sum, value) {
        return sum + value;
    }, 0);

    var pending_percent = +($('.percent').val());

    if (current_percent_sum + pending_percent <= 100) {
        $('body').append('<div class="value" data-value="'+ pending_percent +'">' + pending_percent + '</div>')
    } else {
        alert('You can only enter a max of ' + (100 - current_percent_sum));
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwhPx/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but maybe i explained it wrong. It should only count the percentage of the 3rd input field, the first two will consist of text.